# Javascript - Writing out one letter at a time?

Tags: javascript

Here's what I've done so far:

```
<div id='test'>

</div>

<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
<script>
    var timePerLetter = 2000;
    var newLineCharacter = '|';

    function printOut(text) {
        for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            var CHAR = text[i];

            switch(CHAR) {
                case newLineCharacter:
                    setTimeout( $('#test').append('<br>'), timePerLetter);
                default:
                    setTimeout( $('#test').append(CHAR), timePerLetter);
            }
        }
    }

    printOut("HELLO ASDA| SD");
</script>
```

It prints out as it should, somewhat.
It prints:

```
HELLO ASDA
| SD
```

But, it does **not** wait two seconds per letter, how can I fix this?

Comment: Think for it: you iterate over a string and set `setTimeout` handler to run after `timePerLetter` milliseconds. So there are `text.length` handlers each of which runs simultaneously

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are *synchronously* queueing up a bunch of *asynchronous* operations. So they all execute at about the same time. What you should be doing instead is queueing up the first one and then letting it queue the next one.

```
var timePerLetter = 2000;
var newLineCharacter = '|';

function printOut(text) {
  var index = 0;

  var printNextLetter = function() {
    if (index < text.length) {
      var CHAR = text[index];

      switch(CHAR) {
        case newLineCharacter:
          $('#test').append('<br>');
          break;
        default:
          $('#test').append(CHAR);
          break;
      }

      index++;

      setTimeout(printNextLetter, timePerLetter);
    }
  }

  printNextLetter();
}

printOut("HELLO ASDA| SD");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it does not print out anything now.

Comment: Well, technically, he's not queueing up anything asynchronous, since he's not passing a proper function to setTimeout.

Comment: My apologies. I declared `index` but referred to `i`. Fixed the typo. ;) Should work for you now. Also a good point Shashan! :)

Comment: I should've been able to seen that, haha. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `setTimeout` function to recursively call your `printOut` function, rather than a `for` loop which quickly sets off several `setTimeout`s. Waiting for the `setTimeout` to execute to call `printOut` again gives you a full delay between each `setTimeout`.

To keep track of where the sequence is in the process, an index parameter is added to the `printOut` function, defaulting to *"0"*.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/bbw5bLfo/)

```
var timePerLetter = 2000;
var newLineCharacter = '|';

function printOut(text, ii) {
    ii = ii | 0
    setTimeout(function() {
        var txt = ( newLineCharacter === text[ii] )? '<br>': text[ii]
        $('#test').append(txt)
        printOut(text, ii+=1)
    }, timePerLetter)

}
printOut("HELLO ASDA| SD");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the next `setTimeout` in the previous one. If you set all the timeouts at the beginning, with the same delay, they will run more or less simultaneously.

Moreover, you can just update a text node, instead of the html, to avoid html injection. To preserve newline characters, use the CSS [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property.

```js
var timePerLetter = 500,
    newLineCharacter = '|',
    text = document.createTextNode('');
document.getElementById('test').appendChild(text);
function printOut(str) {
  var i = 0;
  (function main() {
    var char = str[i++];
    text.nodeValue += char == newLineCharacter ? '\n' : char;
    if(i < str.length)
      setTimeout(main, timePerLetter);
  })();
}
printOut("HELLO ASDA| SD");
```

```css
#test {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
var timePerLetter = 200;
var newLineCharacter = '|';

function printOut(text) {
    for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var CHAR = text[i];
        setTimeout(appendLetter, timePerLetter*i, CHAR);
    }
}

function appendLetter(character)
{
    if(newLineCharacter == character)
    {
        $('#test').append('<br>');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#test').append(character);
    }    
}

printOut("HELLO ASDA| SD");
```

Working JSFiddle [here!](https://jsfiddle.net/un0n26wp/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your console - recursive calls with delay:

```
var startStr = 'Hello World';
var shiftAndPrint = function (segments) {
    var segment = segments.shift();
    console.log(segment);
    if (segments.length){
        setTimeout(shiftAndPrint.bind(null,segments),1000);
    }
}
shiftAndPrint(startStr.split(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as the answers using bind, but without using a bind() function.

```js
    var timePerLetter = 2000;
    var newLineCharacter = '|';

    function printOut(text) {
      for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(
          function(j) {
            return function() {
              switch (text[j]) {
                case newLineCharacter:
                  setTimeout($('#test').append('<br>'), timePerLetter);
                  break;
                default:
                  setTimeout($('#test').append(text[j]), timePerLetter);
              }
            }
          }(i),
          timePerLetter * i
        );
      }
    }
    printOut("HELLO ASDA| SD");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'>

</div>
```